# use jquery mmenu with Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, mmenu

I am trying to use [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) in my Magento website. But I can not figure out how to do it.

It works fine as a separate file, but when I insert the same code in a CMS page in Magento, it does not work at all. Please help.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.7.0/js/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
      $('nav#menu').mmenu();
   });
  </script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.7.0/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />
```

```html
<div id="page">
 <div class="">
  <a href="#menu" style="display: block;width: 40px;height: 40px;"></a>
    Demo
 </div>

 <nav id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><span>About us</span>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
     <li><span>The team</span>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#about/team/management">Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about/team/development">Development</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that jquery is running in noconflict mode, so that it can run alongside prototype.

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

 $j(function() {
    $j('nav#menu').mmenu();
 });
```

You should also call js files via local.xml rather than inline.